# Get element within clicked pixel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure where to start on this, I've already Googled for a few days trying to find out how to get the element that is within a selected/clicked pixel on the page. I came across this function from a co-worker but I have no idea what it does:

```
function onclick(e){ 
    var x = e.clientX, 
        y = e.clientY; 

    $("*").filter(function(){ 
        position.left > x && position.left + width < x;
         /*same for height*/;
    }); 
}
```

Put simply, I need to be able to click a pixel and get the div/element that is within that pixel. It's not as simple for my app as just saying `div .class` for example because elements overlap one another with opacity and z-index. [image]

Comment: What do you mean "within the pixel"? Do you mean the element in which the pixel resides?

Comment: @isherwood Basically, where the click is, that's the element it will select. Ignoring the DOM, only grabbing elements where they actually are not by padding, width, margin, etc.

Comment: to see why things happen, using some CSS to set `a { color: transparent; background: red; }` because text elements are rectangles, like every other element without CSS clipping applied. You would literally have to perform close to magic to determine whether where you clicked is whitespace or negative space according to the text engine associated with the string in the element you clicked. So I'm pretty sure this is impossible without some *really* fancy and elaborate code magic.

Comment: OP wants all elements which contain the given point. Hit-testing, that is.

Comment: @MatveyAndreyev Pretty much.

Comment: In that case, the wording of your title and question is backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as shown in the question won't work because variables `position`, `width` are not defined, however its basic idea is correct — loop through all the elements and compare the coordinates of a click to each element's box.

Wanted to try it myself. Moved the working demo [here](http://matvey.kiev.ua/tmp/so/domhittest.html) instead of a snippet.

Comment: **Edit:** moved the demo to an outside page because SO snippet environment was too much for this example.

Comment: That's about what I wanted and I'm going to accept the answer. From what I've read, this is about as good as you can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking wherever in the document will log the clicked element.

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I `do not` want and `will not` work. Elements in my application overlap one another with z-index and opacity, therefore I cannot just select the clicked element, I mush differentiate based on pixel clicked.

Comment: I think it's barely possible. If I'm wrong and it's possible, it will need *a lot of code.*

Comment: @Kinduser Quite possible, and not so much code. See my answer. Though accounting for some funny questions, like what to do with iframes, border-radiuses, etc., will indeed mean much more work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);` if you want to get an element by x and y coords.
See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) for docs.

```
function onclick(e){ 
    var x = e.clientX, 
        y = e.clientY,
        el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/af2m32sv/1/)

Comment: That's a cool method but it returns only the topmost clicked element. The provided MDN article is clear about that.